# Distances between points on a sphere determine them up to isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, inner-products, symmetry, orthogonal-matrices

This is a self-answered question.

Let $v_i,w_i \in \mathbb{S}^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $i=1,\dots,k$ be points on the sphere. Suppose that the Euclidean distances $\|v_i-v_j\|=\|w_i-w_j\|$ for all $i<j$.

How to prove that there exist an isometry $Q \in \text{O}(n)$ such that $Qv_i=w_i$?

---

This question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/862883/unique-euclidean-isometry-between-affinely-independent-points), but here I do not assume independence, the number of points is arbitrary, and they lie on a sphere, so the mapping isometry is actually linear, not just affine.

Alternative solutions are welcome. In particular, I think that it's possible to reduce this question to the mentioned question above in a neat way.

Comment: I don't see how lying on a sphere makes a difference here. (I'm also curious about reconstruction of points given spherical distance).

Comment: Well, it implies that equality of distances implies equality of inner products. And in general the isometric mapping between two configurations with equal distances would be affine, not linear. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/862883/unique-euclidean-isometry-between-affinely-independent-points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matrix-theoretic proof is probably easier in this case, although it is conceptually more opaque. Given two real (tall, square or fat) matrices $V$ and $W$ of the same size, if $V^TV=W^TW$, we want to show that $QV=W$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$.

Clearly $V$ and $W$ have the same rank $r$. Suppose $r>0$. By singular value decomposition, we can construct two rank factorisations $V=U_1R_1^T$ and $W=U_2R_2^T$ such that each $U_i$ has $r$ orthonormal columns and each $R_i$ has full column rank. From $V^TV=W^TW$ we obtain $R_1R_1^T=R_2R_2^T$. Therefore $R_1$ and $R_2$ have the same column space. Hence $R_1=R_2X$ for some invertible matrix $X$ and $R_2XX^TR_2^T=R_2R_2^T$. Since $R_2$ has full column rank, it has a left inverse. Therefore $XX^T=I$, i.e., $X$ is orthogonal. Pick any orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Q(U_1X^T)=U_2$. Then
$$
QV=QU_1R_1^T=QU_1(R_2X)^T=Q(U_1X^T)R_2^T=U_2R_2^T=W.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I just note for future readers that the columns of the matrices $V,W$ correspond to the vectors $v_i,w_i$ in the question. Can you please elaborate on which version of SVD are you using? I am not very familiar with SVD for non-square matrices. In particular, are $U,V$ square matrices, or semi-orthogonal? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix.  If I am not mistaken you are using the version of SVD where the diagonal matrix is square $r \times r$, where $r$ is the rank? ("compact SVD"?). Thanks.

Comment: @AsafShachar I used an economic/compact SVD. The version actually doesn't matter as one can always strip out the singular vectors corresponding to the zero singular values. Anyway, if $A=USV^\ast$ is an economic SVD (uhh, I am running out of symbols; the $V$ here is not the $V$ in our question) where $U,V$ have $r$ columns, $S$ is an $r\times r$ positive diagonal matrix and $r$ is the rank of a matrix $A$, then $A=UR^\ast$ where $U$ has orthonormal columns and $R=VS$ has full column rank.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption implies $$\langle v_i,v_j \rangle=\langle w_i,w_j \rangle. \tag{1}$$

Let $\{v_i \,|\, i \in I\}$ be a **maximal linearly independent set**, where $I \subseteq [k]:=\{1,\dots,k\}$.

Since $\{v_i \,|\, i \in A\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $\{w_i \,|\, i \in A\}$ is linearly independent (as for any $A \subseteq [k], \|a^iw_i\|=\|a^iv_i\|$), $\{w_i \,|\, i \in I\}$ also a maximal linearly independent set.

Define
$$
Q:\text{span}\{v_i\,|\,\,i \in I\} \to \text{span}\{w_i\,|\,\,i \in I\}
$$
by setting $Qv_i=w_i$. $Q$ is an isometry.

Let $j \in \{1,\dots,k\}\setminus I$: Then for any $i \in I$,
$$
\langle Qv_j,w_i \rangle=\langle Qv_j,Qv_i \rangle=\langle v_j,v_i \rangle=\langle w_j,w_i \rangle. \tag{2}
$$

Note that $v_j,w_j$ belong to $\text{span}\{v_i\,|\,\,i \in I\}, \text{span}\{w_i\,|\,\,i \in I\}$ respectively (due to their maximality). Thus $Qv_j,w_j$ both belong to the independent set $\text{span}\{w_i\,|\,\,i \in I\}$, so equation $(2)$ implies that $Qv_j=w_j$. (This is because [the distance to a linearly independent vectors on the sphere determines a point uniquely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470882/the-distance-to-a-linearly-independent-vectors-on-the-sphere-determines-a-point/4470883#4470883)).

Since $\text{span}\{v_i\,|\,\,i \in I\}=\text{span}\{v_i\}_{1\le i \le k}$, we actually constructed an isometry
$$
Q:\text{span}\{v_i\}_{1\le i \le k} \to \text{span}\{w_i\}_{1\le i \le k}
$$
satisfying $Qv_i=w_i$ for every $1 \le i \le k$. Now it is easy to extend $Q$ to an isometry on all $\mathbb{R}^n$ as required.